# Domain Restriction In REST API

Tags: php, web-services, api, curl

I am developing REST API in PHP for a Web Application with key based authentication, I also want to implement DOMAIN restriction for calling the REST API so that it should accessible only from the allowed domains or sub-domains.

For this I tried to fetch the HTTP_REFERRAL from the $_SERVER variable but while calling API though the CURL it does not gives the HTTP_REFERRAL (May be because not calling though the HTTP protocol), Kindly suggest what will be the best way to implement it so that we can get the domain name from the CURL request too.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CORS. Where you can define restriction on domains.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: It seems that it will work with HTTP protocol but my issue is with CURL request. I am good with HTTP and able to fetch the request domain.

Comment: curl sends a http request only. It automates HTTP request.

Comment: The client, curl, sends a HTTP request. The request contains a method (like GET, POST, HEAD etc), a number of request headers and sometimes a request body. The HTTP server responds with a status line (indicating if things went well), response headers and most often also a response body.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Comment: Yes you are correct, but my issue is that I want to fetch the request domain from which my API is calling. Here is the HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME I m getting is the same as my REST API domain in which it is hosted $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] => restapidomain.com, 
$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME] => restapidomain.com. Instead I want to fetch the client domain name to validate